# make log probability plot with desired x-tickmark label and with gridlines in Matlab

Tags: matlab

I would like to make a log-probability plot for my data. I looked up the probplot function and wrote this code

```
x = [0.3,1, 2,5, 2];
probplot('lognormal',x)
```

I would like it to show the grid lines like this plot
http://www.mathworks.com/help/toolbox/stats/wblplot.html

and also relabel x-tickmark at 0, 1 (instead of 10^0), and 100

Thank you for your help!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There you go:

```
x = [0.3, 1, 2,5, 2, 12 25];
probplot('lognormal', x)
grid on
ticks = arrayfun(@num2str, get(gca, 'XTick'), 'UniformOutput', false);
set(gca,'XTickLabel', ticks)
```

Hope that helps :)

Comment: Thank you so much Alexandrew.  Yes, it is exactly what I am after.

Comment: Do you happen to know how to reproduce the graph in R?  Here is a link to my other question.   http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9068778/how-to-create-a-log-probability-plot-in-r